# Angular-ASPnet - Routing Failed

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-routing

After authentication, I need access to my main page.
My controller Angular:

```js
$window.location.href = 'Home/Index';
```

And arrived in my index page, I get the error below:
[image]

I do not understand this error my URL is correct.
thanks
More details :

I have a start page that serve me to login(RouteConfig.cs) :

```js
      name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Authentification", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Once authenticated, I have to go to the main page of the application that contains several pages of content, the main page and the login page are different modules. Here is the script to go to my main page:
And in my main page, which should be displayed first is the homepage according to the script below:

```js
    $routeProvider.otherwise(
                    {
                        redirectTo: '/HomePage'
                    });
```

My problem is that I get to see my main page but I do not get to have the content page HomePage ". (Error 404 failed to load template)

But if I change RouteConfig.cs , its  OK:

```js
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               
            );
```

My problem is the passage from my login page to my main page.
ASP controllers are aLL OK

Config $rootProvider :

```js
var MainApp = angular.module("MainApp",
    [
        "ngRoute",
        "GlobalParamServices",
        "HomePageApp",
        "ListCollaborateurApp",
        "CollaborateurServices",
        "ShowEditCollaborateurApp",
        "AddNewCollaborateurApp",
        "ListRoleApp",
        "ShowEditRoleApp",
        "AddNewRoleApp"
    ]);

//Showing Routing
MainApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    debugger;
    //Main
    $routeProvider.otherwise(
                    {
                        redirectTo: '/HomePage'
                    });
    $routeProvider.when('/HomePage',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'Home/HomePage',
                            controller: 'HomePageController'
                        });
    //Collaborateur
    $routeProvider.when('/ListCollaborateur',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'Collaborateur/ListCollaborateur',
                            controller: 'ListCollaborateurController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/AddNewCollaborateur',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'Collaborateur/AddNewCollaborateur',
                            controller: 'AddNewCollaborateurController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/ShowEditCollaborateur',
                       {
                           templateUrl: 'Collaborateur/ShowEditCollaborateur',
                           controller: 'ShowEditCollaborateurController'
                       });

    //Role
    $routeProvider.when('/ListRole',
                   {
                       templateUrl: 'Role/ListRole',
                       controller: 'ListRoleController'
                   });
    $routeProvider.when('/AddNewRole',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'Role/AddNewRole',
                        controller: 'AddNewRoleController'
                    });

    $routeProvider.when('/ShowEditRole',
                      {
                          templateUrl: 'Role/ShowEditRole',
                          controller: 'ShowEditRoleController'
                      });



    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
}]);
```

Do you have a solution to this case?
Thank you,

Comment: Can you show your full configuration for the `$routeProvider`?

Comment: can I share with you a sample project with google drive?

Comment: Try to prefix the routes with a /, `/Home/HomePage` for instance. Does the other routes work?

Comment: Yes, you might be able to share the project. Send a link and I'll see if I get some time over

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MwmH4847iQMXdiMHE4dGhIZzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a test project .my start page is  the page "page1.cshtml"
Clicking "Go page3" I must have the "page3.cshtml" with the content "Page3_1.cshtml".
I can not have the Page3_1.cshtml

Comment: is you have been looking the example?: )

Comment: You don't have a view for the HomePage action, and you don't have an action in HomeController (which I specified in my answer). When you request /Home/HomePage MVC expects a method in HomeController that matches HomePage, and you need a View that it can return. Is this really the correct project, because you explicitly wrote that you had that code, and you don't in the project you provided?

Comment: the code I sent it's just a test to simulate , but not the real project, thank you I understand it :)

Comment: The thing is that there's a bunch of code missing from your project. You don't have all javascript files you are referencing (like MainApp.js). Also, you are not referencing all files in your scripts folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is complaining about not being able to load the template from the server. You need to add the action in your HomeController for HomePage in order for ASP.NET MVC to return a view.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult HomePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project? If you debug, can you set a breakpoint in the HomePage method?

Comment: The thing is you get a 404, so the server is saying that the resource /Home/HomePage doesn't exist. What happens if you set `$window.location.href = '/Home/HomePage';` instead?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in my "HomePage", the debugger can not enter in. After rebuild , its the same

Comment: Then you have some configuration that blocks access to that page. With the information given I can not determine what that error is, you need to provide more details in that case.

Comment: I changed my post, you can see the details :)